# How to skip the undefined values in an array while running the for loop

Tags: javascript

I have several checkboxes in my webpage table. When the user checks a checkbox (eg number 10) , a marker for number 10  and is saved to my array "currentMarkers" in the 10th position.

```
this.currentMarkers[j] = mymarker;  // where j is the number selected by user
```

Now only the 10th position in the array " currentMarkers" has a value and the rest are undefined since only one checkbox is clicked.

Now the problem I'm facing is that, when i click a main check box i need to clear all the markers in the map by removing the markers from the array. But since currentMarkers[0] has an undefined value ,it shows an error and stops and cannot go forward and remove the currentMarkers[1] , currentMarkers[2] and so on .

```
for(let m =0; m <12; m++){
currentMarkers[m].remove(); // stops as currentMarkers[0] undefined.
}
```

NOTE: If i use the clear array methods the markers will be still in the map. I can only use the .remove() method to remove the markers one by one from the map, and that's why i used the for loop

Is there any way i can look which array values actually have data and use a for loop to iterate through them?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Can you just check if `currentMarkers[m]` exists before trying to call the `remove` method? If optional chaining is available, this could be as easy as `currentMarkers[m]?.remove()`. If not, you could do something like `currentMarkers[m] && currentMarkers[m].remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove only array element that has value.
https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/

```
for(let m =0; m <12; m++){
    if(currentMarkers[m] != undefined || currentMarkers[m] != null) 
    {
        currentMarkers[m].remove(); // stops as currentMarkers[0] undefined.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to check for it, and invoke [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) to skip to the next iteration of the loop:

```js
for(let m =0; m <12; m++){
   if (currentMarkers[m] == undefined) continue;
   currentMarkers[m].remove();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering !! But for some reason it still shows that error. The one @thomson gave seems to work.